# how to wait for onload statement to finish

Tags: javascript

I have an `onload` function within a `for` statement that is producing unexpected results.

The `for` loop loops through an array of images. I'm wanting this loop to execute an `onload` for each image in the array, and only proceed to the next iteration in the `for` loop once that's done. The `onload` is waiting for an image element to load before it executes.

```
  for (index = 0; index < lightboxImages.length; index++) {
    console.log('index :' + index);
    // when the current image has finished loading
    lightboxImages[index].onload = function() {
      console.log('image ' + index + ' loaded.');
    };
  }
```

There are only three elements in the array, and with my `console.log` statements I'm expecting something like this in the console:

```
index : 0
image 0 loaded.
index : 1
image 1 loaded.
index : 2
image 2 loaded.
```

But instead I'm getting output like this:

```
index : 0
index : 1
index : 2
image 3 loaded.
image 3 loaded.
image 3 loaded.
```

How can I prevent iteration until the `onload` is finished?

I also tried something like this:

```
// just an index variable as an example
var counter = 2;

toImage(i) {
  if (i == counter) {
    console.log('hooray');
  }
  else {
    toImage(i++);
  }
}

toImage(0);
```

This was causing a callstack issue that was crashing the page - I didn't include it in the original post, because I figured it was a whole separate issue, but maybe I should have in retrospect. I guess my attempt at recursion here is wrong.

Comment: Assigning to `.onload` does install an event handler, it doesn't block and wait until that event has occurred.

Comment: This isn't possible as written.  You'll need some kind of queue or recursion. (that said.... if you're just preloading images, i suggest looking for a script, there's hundreds that already do this.)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) on why you are getting `image 3` three times. Maybe that helps you to get a solution that doesn't need to stop iterating?

Comment: I did try a recursive function, but that was causing me problems, too - I'll add that to my code above

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I'm checking this out

Comment: @KevinB thanks for the dupe question, checking that one out, too

Comment: here's another, though dunno if the answer works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702735/preload-images-with-queuing

Comment: And here's a much older, more comprehensive/popular thread on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901677/the-definitive-best-way-to-preload-images-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, I added the recursion I previously tried above, but I guess I didn't do it right. I'll check out your resources

Comment: This is absolutely not a duplicate question, at least not for the question you linked. This question is about closure and scope, not image preloading.

Comment: `++` -> `++i` you forgot `i`, and want to increment it before it gets passed as a parameter.

Comment: oops, sorry, it was originally `i++` in my code, I updated the question

Comment: definitely reading up on `++i` vs `i++`, thank you @KevinB

Comment: @rpivovar, please note that poster has misunderstood your question. His proposed solution will not fix your problem.

Comment: @NickCoad I agree the preloading stuff is not exactly what I'm looking for, but the recursion fix is definitely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An alternative is recursive calls:**

```
function loop(lightboxImages, index) {
    if (index === lightboxImages.length) return;

    lightboxImages[index].onload = function() {
      console.log('image ' + index + ' loaded.');
      loop(lightboxImages, ++index);
    };
}

loop(lightboxImages, 0);
```

Comment: yeah I was doing `index++` and not `++index` - will give this a try and come back

Comment: @rpivovar ok ok `:)`

Comment: There is no need for recursion in this example.

Comment: @NickCoad can you explain?

Comment: See my answer. The issue @rpivovar has encountered is a common one caused by scope and variables being passed by reference. The usual solution is to use a closure to capture the variable.

Comment: To be clear, your answer will still work so I'm not knocking it.

Comment: @NickCoad no, each image needs to wait until the previous image is totally downloaded from the server.  This is not a problem regarding to variable scope.

Comment: @Ele ah, I see the confusion, my apologies.

Comment: @NickCoad no problem `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a closure.

```js
var someFakeImages = [
  { onload: function () {} },
  { onload: function () {} },
  { onload: function () {} }
];

var onloadFunc = function(i) {
    return function () {
        console.log('image ' + i + ' loaded.');
    }
};

for (index = 0; index < someFakeImages.length; index++) {
    console.log('index: ' + index);

    // when the current image has finished loading
    someFakeImages[index].onload = onloadFunc(index);
}

someFakeImages[0].onload();
someFakeImages[1].onload();
someFakeImages[2].onload();
```

You can find out more about closures on the MDN website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Basically with the above, you are creating a new function with a snapshot of the value of `index` at the time of assigning the onload handler. In your posted code, you are actually using the current value of `index` at the time of *executing* the onload handler.

Answer (score 0):

You console.log is showing the CURRENT value of index. You see, the loop has finished and index is now at 3 when the onloads are fired. You need to pass the index as a LOCAL variable to the onload handler.

It is a common 'issue' for many programmers in dealing with asynchronous coding ;)

Comment: The explanation is fine, but your thought is wrong.

Comment: I am 52 years old and have owned/built IT/tech companies and employed programmers since 1986 (from Sri Lanka, India, USA, Canada, UK, Australia, etc), which 'thought' is wrong?

Comment: The code snippet that follows "I would think" doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I know, It was just an example to get the person asking the question on the right track. That is why I said 'think'.... How about now :)

Comment: Still no. Maybe better explain your thought rather than posting a code snippet.

Comment: Ok, getting too old for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to `onload` only assigns an event handler: it doesn't mean that the current thread stops and waits for the load to finish. I suggest using `reduce` and `await` instead.

```
function loadImages(lightboxImages) {
  lightboxImages.reduce(async (lastPromise, image, i) => {
    await lastPromise;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      image.onload = () => {
        console.log(`image ${i} loaded.`);
        resolve();
      };
    });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: Don't make it any more complicated than it needs to be with that `reduce`. If you are going to use `async`/`await` anyway, just loop directly (with `for (const [i, image] of lightboxImages.entries())`) and `await` each one.